# Powershell memory exhaustion using NTFSSecurity module on a deep folder traverse

Tags: powershell, acl, ntfs

I have been tasked with reporting all of the ACL's on each folder in our Shared drive structure. Added to that, I need to do a look up on the membership of each unique group that gets returned.

Im using the NTFSSecurity module in conjunction with the get-childitem2 cmdlet to get past the 260 character path length limit. The path(s) I am traversing are many hundreds of folders deep and long since pass the 260 character limit.

I have been banging on this for a couple of weeks. My first challenge was crafting my script to do my task all at once, but now im thinking thats my problem... The issue at hand is resources, specifically memory exhaustion. Once the script gets into one of the deep folders, it consumes all RAM and starts swapping to disk, and I eventually run out of disk space.

Here is the script:

```
$csvfile = 'C:\users\user1\Documents\acl cleanup\dept2_Dir_List.csv'

foreach ($record in Import-Csv $csvFile)
{

$Groups = get-childitem2 -directory -path $record.FullName -recurse | Get-ntfsaccess | where -property accounttype -eq -value group
$groups2 = $Groups | where -property account -notmatch -value '^builtin|^NT AUTHORITY\\|^Creator|^AD\\Domain'
$groups3 = $groups2 | select account -Unique

 $GroupMembers = ForEach ($Group in $Groups3) {
    (Get-ADGroup $Group.account.sid | get-adgroupmember | select Name, @{N="GroupName";e={$Group.Account}}

)}
$groups2 | select FullName,Account,AccessControlType,AccessRights,IsInherited | export-csv "C:\Users\user1\Documents\acl cleanup\Dept2\$($record.name).csv"
$GroupMembers | export-csv "C:\Users\user1\Documents\acl cleanup\Dept2\$($record.name)_GroupMembers.csv"
}
```

NOTE: The dir list it reads in is the top level folders created from a get-childitem2 -directory | export-csv filename.csv

During the run, it appears to not be flushing memory properly. This is just a guess from observation. At the end of each run through the code, the variables should be getting over-written, I thought, but memory doesn't go down, so it looked to me that since memory didn't go back down, that it wasn't properly releasing it? Like I said, a guess... I have been reading about runspaces but I am confused about how to implement that with this script. Is that the right direction for this?

Thanks in advance for any assistance...!

Comment: _The path(s) I am traversing are many hundreds of folders deep_ geez, I wonder what lead to this situation. This will bring countless issues if working with Windows... not only for you but also for the users.

Comment: Agreed, completely. This is the first step in remediation. I have to know what groups have access to what before we can talk about moving the structure to a cleaner, more organized environment. I always knew the 260 character limit existed, but cant say that I remember ever having to really deal with it. Here, every day. I thank the powershell gods daily for alphafs.dll and the get-childitem2 cmdlet.

Comment: I've got a similar script and added the line $ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue' at the start so I don't see the error message using "Get-ChildItem". A try{}catch{} should dispose of the error in your foreach. a filter on the filename could either get a list of these long folder names or ignore them : Get-ChildItem  | ? {$_.FullName.length -lt 255}

Comment: That is a good idea but, for this example, I definitely need to get into those directories to find out what the security of them are. I can't recommend the NTFSSecurity module highly enough, if for nothing else, having to never deal with the 260 character limit again!

Comment: did you check if any of your objects you instantiate can be `Dispose()`d? of yes I would do so. If not I would traverse the directory tree via recursion and create a new instance of it on every *n* recursion (starting at the lowest level). By running the scripts separately (and in separate powershell sessions) you can reclaim all the memory once you exit. Maybe this can help to mitigate your memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Funny you should post about this as I just finished a modified version of the script that I think works much better. A friend turned me on to 'Function Filters' that seem to work well here. Ill test it on the big directories tomorrow to see how much better the memory management is but so far it looks great.

```
    #Define the function ‘filter’ here and call it ‘GetAcl’. Process is the keyword that tells the function to deal with each item in the pipeline one at a time
Function GetAcl {

            PROCESS {
            Get-NTFSAccess $_  | where -property accounttype -eq -value group | where -property account -notmatch -value '^builtin|^NT AUTHORITY\\|^Creator|^AD\\Domain'
                    }
                } 

#Import the directory top level paths
$Paths = import-csv 'C:\users\rknapp2\Documents\acl cleanup\dept2_Dir_List.csv'

#Process each line from the importcsv one at a time and run GetChilditem against it. 
#Notice the second part – I ‘|’ pipe the results of the GetChildItem to the function that because of the type of function it is, handles each item one at a time
#When done, pass results to Exportcsv and send it to a file name based on the path name. This puts each dir into its own file.
 ForEach ($Path in $paths) {
 (Get-ChildItem2 -path $path.FullName -Recurse -directory) | getacl | export-csv "C:\Users\rknapp2\Documents\acl cleanup\TestFilter\$($path.name).csv" }
```